# Read an int[] from a DataInputStream

Tags: java, file-io, java-io, datainputstream

I'm looking for a way to read a large number of ints from a DataInputStream and load them into an array. I know exactly how many `int`s I need to read, but it'd be nice if there was a cleaner way than to simply iterate.

There is already a way to do this with a byte array, just by using the `DataInputStream#read(byte[])` method, but there is no equivalent for `int[]`. I could obviously read the data into a byte array by creating a byte array with the length multiplied by four, but I really need the data in `int`s.

The way I see it, there are three possibilities I could use:

1. Somehow load the data directly into an `int[]`.
2. Somehow convert a `byte[]` into an `int[]`.
3. Iterate through the array and just use `readInt()`.

While the first two solutions are much preferred, I currently don't know of a way to do either. Is there any simple way to do this without iteration?

Comment: It seems to me that readInt() in a loop should work fine.  If properly opened the DataInputStream should be buffered so the overhead would be minimal.

Comment: @HotLicks That might be what I end up doing. I'd just love for this particular bit of code to be as fast as possible, since my application will probably be doing a lot of File IO.

Comment: Unless you get into the nio stuff (if even there), or maybe native method stuff, there's no way to do memory-mapped I/O such that you could write directly to an array of int.

Comment: @HotLicks faced the same problem. Do you mean `dataInStream.readInt()` doesn't make I/O call to a file system, but wait till you make another operations. But how does it know that you gonna do another operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the only way to do this is a simple for loop and using `readInt()`. This is what I eventually opted to do.

Comment: haven't you find any more effective way to read lots of integers? I have a binary file which ocnsists only from integers, there are millions of integers. Is `while` loop with `readInt` the best choice? P.S. the binary file is formed by me, if needed I can change file format

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `ByteBuffer`, which is able to leave the data in the OS memory and therefore reads pretty quick. It also has a `getInt()` method, which should allow you to directly read Integers and put them into your array.

Comment: Would just be more overhead vs readInt() from the DataInputStream.

Comment: Another problem here is that I'm actually using the `DataInputStream` for much more than just this int array. This is only a portion of the data. I can't really go for another approach without drastically increasing the amount of work I need to do.

Comment: @JakeKing With DataInputStream your best and only option is to use a loop with `readInt()`. I would make sure you are using BufferedInputStream as well. ;)